# MOCA between DSL modem and router in separate location

Tags: networking, home-networking

Due to very few options in my neighborhood, I have a very slow DSL connection and a faster 4GLTE connection and a dual WAN balancing router. My issue is that I really need my 4G router to be on the 3rd floor for better reception while my DSL router has to be on the 1st (without paying a ton to run the DSL line all the way upstairs).

I have coax ports in every room and I'm wondering if I can use MoCa between the DSL modem and the router while having the 4g modem plugged in directly to the router on the 3rd floor (so basically using MOCA as an extension of the WAN line).

So it would look like this:

**3rd floor:** 4G Modem > WAN1 in router

**1st floor:** DSL modem> MOCA adapter> coax port (1st floor) > coax port (3rd floor)> MOCA adapter> WAN2 in router

Note: The coax network is unused currently (I don't have cable) so there should be no interference.

Comment: grawity gave you the answer, just want to add, as an option you can use also `Powerline Ethernet adapters`, in most cases it might be cheaper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes – as long as MoCA adapters act as transparent Ethernet bridges, the modem and router won't notice a difference. However, make sure not to accidentally mix the DSL WAN and your LAN into the same MoCA network.

(And if this doesn't work out, then IMHO the next option should be to run Ethernet, *not* DSL, through the floors. If your DSL link is already unreliable, increasing the distance even more wouldn't be a good idea.)

Comment: OK. Thanks. I have an Ethernet LAN but have not been able to figure out how to route WAN over it at the same time. Hence running the DSL idea.

Comment: Ethernet switches with 802.1Q VLAN tagging are usually used for that purpose. One on 1st floor, and one on 3rd (unless the router already supports 802.1Q VLANs by itself).